# how display function work in opengl for showing a bmp 8 bits/pixel image (cpp)

Tags: c++, image, opengl, bmp

I want to show a 8 bit/pixel bmp image with opengl.

This is the code:

```
void paint (void) {

    //read and draw a bit map file
    unsigned char pixel;
    GLint x, y, xs, xf, ys, i, pix, xpack;
    GLfloat pixtmp[3];
    ofstream debug( "image.txt",ios::out);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    ifstream inpaint( "image.bmp", ios::binary);
    //w=640
    if(!inpaint) {
        cout << "File not opened\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    for(x=1; x<=54; x++) {
        inpaint>>pixel; //go to start of data after header stuff
        pix = pixel;
        debug << pix << endl; //file data for explanation purpose
    }
    debug << "End of Header?" << endl;
    xs = 1;
    xf = ww; //should get x & y from header really
    xpack = xf%4; //multiples of 4 bytes/x line
    ys = 0;
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (y=ys; y<= wh; y++) {
        for (x = xf; x>= xs; x--){ //earth_r.bmp
            inpaint>>pixel;
            for (i=0; i<=2; i++) { //3 bytes = 1 pixel in 24 bit colour
                pix = pixel;
                debug << pix << " ";
                pixtmp[i] = float(pix)/255.0;
            }
            debug << endl;
            glColor3f(pixtmp[2], pixtmp[1], pixtmp[0]); //G B R !
            glVertex2i(x,y);
        }
        if(xpack != 0) for (i=1; i<=xpack; i++) inpaint>>pixel;
    } //next raster line y
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
```

but as you see the right picture is what I'm trying to show and the left one is what shown with my function
[image]

I checked the numbers and played around with them but it still doesn't work.

I think the problem is with:

```
if(xpack != 0) for (i=1; i<=xpack; i++) inpaint>>pixel;
```

And that each pixel line should be a multiple of 4

Comment: Each line in a .bmp is padded to  a multiple of 4 **bytes**, not pixels.  Also, line padding only needs to be computed once, then reused for each line, because the lines are all the same size.  In  your code, the variable `ww` is crucial to understanding what might be going wrong, but it is never defined and its value never set.  But if you have a 24bpp image whose width is 640: <line byte count> = 640 * 3 = 1920 bytes per line (before padding).  Then for padding: 1920 bytes % 4 = 0 -- meaning there is no line byte padding for this file.

Comment: i set height and width manually
GLsizei wh = 512; // height of window
GLsizei ww = 512; // width of window

Comment: 512 has a factor of 4, so padding will not be present.  You should test your program with the padding code commented out, just to test if your suspicion is correct.

Comment: i try comment padding code even use a different image resolution
+ use (width*3)%4 but still doesn't work

but when i try a different image that just include the simple lines, code work perfect for that, but for lena image or other image it doesn't work
thanks for your time

Comment: I see in the code that your `ifstream` is being openend with the binary flag, but is there any chance that the bad Lena image was opened as text? The distortion is chaotic, like it might originate from the pixel data itself -- removing the `0x0d` byte whenever a `0x0d 0x0a` pair is encountered might create a similar effect.  This would normally cause color distortion, but the fact this is a grayscale image would mask this symptom.

Comment: thank you so much, i try using `inpaint.get(pixel)` instead `inpaint>>pixel` and it work perfect